# Multiple Elements with same accesskey : Imitate IE-Behaviour in Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

In our project, we are switching from Internet Explorer (IE-Mode in Edge, to be precise) to Edge. This causes a problem with multiple HTML-elements that share the same value for their `acceskey` attribute. It works fine in IE, but when using Edge, the wrong element is activated. According to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-accesskey-attribute/) , the reason seems to be that those two browsers have different behaviours for which element is activated when the acceskey is pressed:

> ```
> Google Chrome and Safari: The last element with the accesskey will be activated
> ...
> Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox: The next element with the accesskey will be activated
> ```

Is there a way to imitate the behaviour of IE in Edge?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Edge IE mode use the Trident engine, which is completely different from Chromium Edge, so I don't think your needs can be achieved. In short, this is by design.

I was thinking that as an alternative, you can try to use scripts to detect what the current browser is(Edge or Edge IE mode), and add `accesskey` attribute based on the result, or add the element in page document.

But if you're using the same key to trigger them all, this alternative probably won't work either.